# How to get the value of a slider in ApplescriptObjC?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

`property slider : missing value`

`if slider's integerValue = 5 then
-- Do something
end if`

This code won't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: integerValue() returns a cocoa class. You always want to explicitly coerce numbers into an Applescript class if you're going to use them further in Applescript, to add an "as integer" when you get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log class of slider's integerValue` returns something called `__NSCFNumber`

`log class of 5` returns `<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'long'>`

Looks like Applescript does not automatically convert the values for you. To get it working a (*strange looking*) conversion will do it:

```
if slider's integerValue as integer = 5 then
    -- Do something
end if
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg